# mysqli driver not found in xamp when using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

hi i am trying to use pdo to connect to my mysqli database on xamp and i keep getting this error.

php connection code

```
$handler = new PDO('mysqli:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=app','root','');
```

error message

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in

Comment: the only drivers i have access to are mysql and sqlite

Comment: MySQLi and PDO are two *different* things.  The database is MySQL.  MySQLi is one way of accessing it and PDO is another.

Answer (score 2):

remove the i from mysqli:

```
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=app','root','');
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQLi is not a driver for PDO. It is a standalone class. PDO has the following drivers:

- CUBRID (PDO)
- MS SQL Server (PDO)
- Firebird (PDO)
- IBM (PDO)
- Informix (PDO)
- MySQL (PDO)
- MS SQL Server (PDO)
- Oracle (PDO)
- ODBC and DB2 (PDO)
- PostgreSQL (PDO)
- SQLite (PDO)
- 4D (PDO)

More information you can find here: http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.drivers.php
You have to remove the `i` from the dsn: `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=app`